# Function colors cells which match specific condition

Tags: excel, vba, function, colors, cell

I want to code a function `color_yellow(table As Range)` which outputs table with colored cells in which numbers are smaller than 0.5.

**Example**

[image]

My pseudo code :

```
Function color_yellow(table As Range)
    Dim temp As Variant, i As Long
    temp = table.Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(temp, 1)
        If temp(i, 1) < 0.5 Then
           fill_with_yellow (temp(i, 1))
        End If
    Next
   
    color_yellow = temp

End Function
```

I called it 'pseudo code' because there is no such function as `fill_with_yellow`. Do you know by what should I replace `fill_with_yellow(temp(i,1))` to get expected result ?

**EDIT**

Using conditional formatting :
I found that color which interests me has number `65535`.

I know that If I want to have my condition I only have to use :

```
With Cells(1, 1).FormatConditions.add(xlCellValue, xlLess, "=0.5")
    .Color = 65535
    .StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

But I'm not sure how to add this to my function color_yellow.

Comment: a variant array cannot hold formatting you will need to put the values in the cell then iterate and format the cells.

Comment: Why are you not using conditional formatting for this? Seems like you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: So how it can be performed using conditional formatting ?

Comment: You can create a rule based on the cell value.. It's very straightforward. Please give it a shot.

Comment: CF: 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'; add in a formula such as "=IF(A1<0.5,TRUE,FALSE)" then set the format for when it's true (i.e. fill yellow)

Comment: Thanks for you help you all! I updated my question. I found code and color number which I need but I don't know how to add this to my function. Please have a look at my question updated.

Comment: You don't need VBA; 65535 =  #FFFF00; this can be edited in the fill color under 'More colors' by directly changing the RBF values

Comment: Yes, I mean I know I can do it at Excel level, but I prefer to have it done at VBA level.

Comment: Here is [one link](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html) and [another link](https://exceljet.net/conditional-formatting-with-formulas) for examples on how to apply conditional formatting to your sheet.

Comment: Thank you all for your tips, however you're all giving me tips how to do it in excel, wheres I want to have a function in VBA.

Comment: A UDF called from a worksheet cannot alter the sheet such as by coloring various cells - it can only return a value.